# Can't Access WS02 IDS Management Console

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to configure a fresh install of the WSO2 IDS on my local machine for development purposes.

When I try to log onto the management console at https://localhost:9443/ with the default admin credentials the website displays an error: 
"Login failed! Please recheck the username and password and try again."

When I look at the audit.log I see:
INFO {AUDIT_LOG}-  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2017-10-06 17:20:13,537-0500]

When I look at the http_access.log I am seeing:
"POST /carbon/admin/js/csrfPrevention.js HTTP/1.1" 200 63 "https://localhost:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp?loginStatus=false"

I've checked to make sure csrf is turned off during debugging this in the following locations. I don't see any reference to CSRF in these files:
- /repository/conf/carbon.xml
- /repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml
- /repository/conf/tomcat/carbon/WEB-INF/web.xml
- /WEB-INF/web.xml

The install is a fresh download of wso2-5.3. The only configuration change from the default download I have made is to /repository/conf/tomcat/carbon/WEB-INF/web.xml where I disabled the captcha filter (it wouldn't start with captcha enabled).

I'm not sure what the problem is, but would appreciate any help

edit:
I found the answer in the WSO2 Jira (sorry not enough rep to link)

The guides tell you to start the server with the following command:
sh bin/wso2server.sh -DworkerNode

If you remove -DworkerNode it works.

Comment: Since it is fresh download and you observe that it does not start with  captcha enabled, which means something wrong in your environment. Can you check 1) if you run Java7 or Java8 ? 2) none of the ports needed by IS are already open? 3) Any file system permission or capacity errors?

Comment: I confirmed the required ports are opened. I'm running Java 8. When I enable captcha in the web.xml I get a class not found error specifically: Exception starting filter CaptchaFilter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.identity.captcha.filter.CaptchaFilter

Comment: `If you remove -DworkerNode it works.` WSO2IS has no worker node / mode. Do not use it for WSO2IS. Which guide stated you shoud start with the `workerNode`? (rather start with `-Dsetup` )

Answer (score 0):

See the first tip in this document:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+Identity+Server+5.1.0%2C+5.2.0+and+5.3.0